# Programmatic access to Azure's CloudConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, azure

I'm using a [CloudConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager_members.aspx) to access runtime settings. But, the interface is terrible! There is just 1 static GetSetting() method. I'm guessing this is because the underlying logic is just lazily searching a variety of locations for the key at runtime.

What I would like to do is iterate over all possible keys. The more basic ConfigurationManager class accomplishes this via a method AppSettings().

I figure this might /not/ be possible via CloudConfigurationManager, but I wonder if there is a way to access the schema file (the .csdef) in some programmatic way (i.e. strongly typed manner). I would prefer not to access it as raw XML. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems to be a repeat of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710494/how-to-get-all-configuration-settings-from-azure-config-file

Answer (score 1):

> but I wonder if there is a way to access the schema file (the .csdef)
>   in some programmatic way (i.e. strongly typed manner).

From what I understand, this is by design. You're not supposed to access it programmatically. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee758711.aspx:

> The service definition file defines the service model for an
>   application.

The way I understand this is essentially `csdef` file is the model you configure and tell `Azure Fabric Controller` how your resources should be deployed and configured e.g. Size of VM, should you require IIS, what certificates to install, firewall ports to open etc. Azure Fabric Controller takes this information and stands up the environment for you.

This is the reason why `csdef` file is bundled with the package and not kept as a separate file like `cscfg` file.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I only mentioned the csdef as a secondary solution, if one existed. This is getting frustrating. Azure has some sort of way to read configuration settings and iterate over the values, because they're being displayed in the Azure portal. I don't see why the SDK team would explicitly prohibit this functionality. I'll keep digging. 

There is a way to receive callback events when a config setting is changed in the portal (https://convective.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/service-runtime-in-windows-azure/) - But this doesn't address my need to access all of the settings

Comment: `Azure has some sort of way to read configuration settings and iterate over the values, because they're being displayed in the Azure portal` - My guess is that they are also parsing the XML file. Schema for cscfg file is defined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee758710.aspx. If I am not misaken, they don't show the values from csdef file.

Comment: Right - and I wouldn't want the values. You could simply parse the def file to get the keys and then perform a lookup on each key using the CloudConfigurationManager class.